# Wrong resultCode on poco phone

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, xiaomi

Uploading an image to firebase. There is no problem when downloading from android emulator or oppo phone, but when starting the project from poco m3 phone, no upload occurs.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) { super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); if (requestCode == RC_IMAGE_PICKER&& resultCode == RESULT_OK){ Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData(); StorageReference imageReference = chatImagesStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment()); UploadTask uploadTask = imageReference.putFile(selectedImageUri); uploadTask = imageReference.putFile(selectedImageUri);    
Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                throw task.getException();
            }

            // Continue with the task to get the download URL
            return imageReference.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                AwesomeMessage message = new AwesomeMessage();
                message.setImageUrl(downloadUri.toString());
                message.setName(userName);
                messagesDatabaseReferences.push().setValue(message);

            } else {

                // Handle failures
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

By trial, I determined that when starting from the phone, resultCode = 0, with which I can’t understand it connected. Everything else except resultCode works properly.

When running the application on the android emulator or on oppo , there were no problems, the pictures were sent, but nothing happened when sending from the poco m3.

Comment: Are you getting any failures when the task is not successful?

Comment: I don't get any errors, no action happens after failure.

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: Yes, onComplete works, but gives the wrong resultCode, when i chose photo on poco m3

Comment: What is the exact resultCode that you get?

Comment: resulting resultСode = 0